# Can I make a changing input message from a list in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, input

I am creating a code where there is a list with names and the code asks for each person's age. Is it possible to create a for looped input with the message always changing corresponding to the name?

I have tried the print syntax but it did not seem to work:

```
ages = [0] * 3

names = ["Julia", "Benjamin", "George"]

for i in range (0, 3):
    ages[i] = int(input("How old is", names[i]))

print(ages)
```

The expected output would be a list containing the ages, for example:

`[23, 19, 34]`

but I only get an error message:

`TypeError: raw_input() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.`

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Use string formatting or concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the line :

```
ages[i] = int(input("How old is", names[i]))
```

By :

```
ages[i] = int(input("How old is" + names[i]))
```

The reason is with the "+" you create a new string,
so it counted as only 1 argument.

Answer (score 1):

`input` doesn't use the same syntax as `print`, so you can't write:

```
input("How old is", names[i]) # doesn't work!!
```

but you have to pass input a complete string, like:

```
input("How old is {}?".format(names[i]))
```

Note that you can (and should) avoid using indices when looping:

```
names = ["Julia", "Benjamin", "George"]
ages = []

for name in names:
    ages.append(int(input("How old is {}?".format(name)))

print(ages)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use string formatting:

```
input(f"How old is {names[i]}?")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for i in range (0, 3):
    ages[i] = int(input("How old is "+names[i]))
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
How old is Julia20
How old is Benjamin50
How old is George8
>>> ages
[20, 50, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ages[i] = int(input("How old is " + names[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You gave two args to input() by separating them with a comma. Try

```py
for i in range (0, 3):
    ages[i] = int(input("How old is " + names[i]))
```

or

```py
for i in range (0, 3):
    ages[i] = int(input("How old is {}".format(names[i])))
```